# proper way of connecting to twitter using twitter-hbc in multithreaded system

Tags: java, multithreading, twitter, twitter4j, twitter-hbc

I am having a use-case in which I am consuming twitter filter stream in a multithreaded environment using **twitter** **HBC**.

I receive keywords to track from user on per request that I receive, process them and save them to the database.
Example

- Request 1: track keywords [apple, google]
- Request 2: track keywords [yahoo, microsoft]

What I am currently doing is, opening a new thread for each request and processing them.

I am making connection for every end-pints a below ([I am following this official HBC example](https://github.com/twitter/hbc/blob/master/hbc-example/src/main/java/com/twitter/hbc/example/FilterStreamExample.java))

```
endpoint.trackTerms(Lists.newArrayList("twitterapi", "#yolo"));

    Authentication auth = new OAuth1(consumerKey, consumerSecret, token, secret);

    // Create a new BasicClient. By default gzip is enabled.
    Client client = new ClientBuilder()
            .hosts(Constants.STREAM_HOST)
            .endpoint(endpoint)
            .authentication(auth)
            .processor(new StringDelimitedProcessor(queue))
            .build();

    // Establish a connection
    client.connect();


The problem that I am facing is twitter gives me warning of having more that one connection.
```

But as according to the above code and my use case **I have to make a new instance of  `Client` object for ever request that I receive as my end points 
(trackTerms) are different for every request that I receive**.

**What is the proper way to connect to twitter for my use-case (multithreaded system)** to avoid `to many connections warning` and `rate limit warnings`

Current warnings from twitter:

```
2017-02-01 13:47:33 INFO TwitterStreamImpl:62 - 420:Returned by the Search and Trends API when you are being rate limited (https://dev.twitter.com/docs/rate-limiting).
Returned by the Streaming API:
Too many login attempts in a short period of time.
Running too many copies of the same application authenticating with the same account name.
Exceeded connection limit for user
```

Thanks.

Comment: The "default" answer would be to look out for some sort of pooling; but I too far away from the depths of this API; so I can't tell you how to do that here.

Comment: I din't find anything similar to pooling in docs. did I missed something?

Comment: As said; I am not an expert here. What I mean is: in general, when you have many parallel "activities" that deal with the same "endpoint" (like a database for example) you look into pooling the "access elements". Be assured; if I had the slightest idea to put down a helpful answer, I would have written it already ;-)

Comment: @GhostCat ok thanks.